# Filtering using advanced filter in a DOORS module

Tags: excel, loops, filter, ibm-doors

I am new to dxl. Here I am trying to extract few attributes from a formal module in DOORS by applying advanced filter to an excel sheet.

- Manual method :

Filters applied are:

1.In attribute = "Customer_ContentType" = "requirement"

2.In Links -> no in link and no out link

then we will export the filtered content to excel and remove the main content and use the required attribute columns.

The dxl script I have written to solve this issue is not giving the expected results.

I have tried to take the required data to excel by applying the filter in doors. But I am facing issue while using DXL Script

code:

```
    Filter req = attribute "Customer_ContentType" == "Requirement"
    Filter link = no in-link && no out-link
    Filter crsfilter =  (req && link)
    filtering on  
    addFilter(crsfilter)
    set( crsfilter)
    refresh current
```

//then script to add to excel sheet

Expected output :
An excel sheet with following listed out :

[image: Excel output after filtering]

Only these values excluding the main content should be extracted to excel.

With this function i am not able to get this output, I am getting error and exiting by preventing further execution.

Comment: Ok, so which one is your question?

Comment: @DavidGarcíaBodego , this function i am using is having some issue, so the filtering is not working, could you please suggest some improvements to be done on this.

Answer (score 0):

If this is an accurate copy of your code:

```
Filter req = attribute "Customer_ContentType" == "Requirement"
Filter link = no in-link && no out-link
Filter crsfilter =  (req && link)
filtering on  
addFilter(crsfilter)
set( crsfilter)
refresh current
```

You will want to look into the 'hasNoLinks' filter

```
Filter req = attribute "Customer_ContentType" == "Requirement"
Filter link = hasNoLinks(linkFilterBoth,"*")
Filter crsfilter = ( req && link )
filtering on
addFilter ( crsfilter )
refresh current
```

That's if I'm understanding your issue correctly.